# How to override __call__ in celery on main?

Tags: python, django, celery

I've been using an abstract Task and overriding the `__call__` method to handle some things before each task executed like such:

```
class CoreTaskHandler(Task):
    abstract = True
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

But the `__call__` method gets executed on the worker, I need some override that will get executed on main, not the worker each time the task gets "delayed".

Does anyone have an idea how would I go on about doing that?

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed this by overriding the apply_sync method in Task:

```
class CoreTaskHandler(Task):
    abstract = True
    def apply_async(self, *args, **kwargs):

        ........

        return super(CoreTaskHandler, self).apply_async(*args, **kwargs)
```