# How to handle errors in celery's Task.map

Tags: python, dictionary, exception, celery

Say I have two celery tasks:

```
@celery.task
def run_flakey_things(*args, **kwargs):
    return run_flakey_and_synchronous_thing.map(
        xrange(10)
    ).apply_async()


@celery.task
def run_flakey_and_synchronous_thing(a):
    if a % 5:
        return a
    raise RuntimeError(a)
```

So when you go to run `run_flakey_things` it'll fall over straight away because the first item in the sequence raises an exception. What I would like is to run the task for all items in the sequence **in order** as map does, but continue to run on exception, raising a new exception once all of these have completed.

The ideal would be if I could add an on_failure to the `xmap` object before applying it, but `xmap` does not appear to be a full task object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your return value to indicate and propagate the errors. Like so:

```
import traceback

@celery.task
def run_flakey_things(*args, **kwargs):
    return run_flakey_and_synchronous_thing.map(
        xrange(10)
    ).apply_async()


@celery.task
def run_flakey_and_synchronous_thing(a):
    d = {'value': None, 'error': None}
    try:
        if a % 5:
            d['value'] = a
    except:
        d['error'] = traceback.format_exc()
    return d
```

You can then do a few things:

1) Change your run_flakey_things to group things with and without errors, return the ones without errors and report the ones with errors.

2) Handle that behavior in whatever is calling run_flakey_things

Answer (score 0):

I have not used celery.  However could you add a `__call__` method to the subtask?  Something like:

```
class MyTask:
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        try: 
            super(self, MyTask).__call__(*args, **kwargs) 
        except Exception, exc:
            # store exc to be raised later in the main task

@celery.task(base=MyTask):
def run_flakey_and_synchronous_thing(a):
    # ...
```

Then for the main `run_flakey_things` task, perhaps override `apply_async()` to retrieve the stored exception, as in [How to override __call__ in celery on main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574395/how-to-override-call-in-celery-on-main).